# Bash -s option: "no arguments remain after option processing"

Tags: bash

I was reading the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) in order to understand the `-s` option when invoking `bash`. The first sentence says:

> -s If this option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.

What does "no arguments remain after option processing" mean? Eventually, all options will be processed and there won't be any options/arguments left to process, right?

I need to know the difference between using `bash -s` and without (i.e., `bash`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will run `script` with arguments `arg1` and `arg2`:

```
bash script arg1 arg2
```

With `-s`, something very different happens: an *interactive* shell is started and any remaining arguments to bash are interpreted not as commands to but only as positional arguments:

```
$ bash -s arg1 arg2
$ echo "0=$0  1=$1  2=$2"
0=bash  1=arg1  2=arg2
```

In the above, `echo "0=$0  1=$1  2=$2"` was typed in by hand at the interactive prompt for the new shell.

Comment: Do you have a use case in mind where it's powerful ?

Comment: Ah...I think I finally understand what "if no arguments remain after option processing" means. It means there are no arguments other than options. So this implies the two commands `bash` and `bash -s` (with no further arguments) are equivalent, and both start interactive shells. Am I right?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Sometimes, when testing script commands, I find it useful to have the positional arguments set.  I would usually set them, though, with `set -- arg1 arg2` rather than `bash -s arg1 arg2`.  So, no, I have no powerful use case.

Comment: @flow2k Yes, as far as I can tell, the commands `bash` and `bash -s`, with no additional arguments, are equivalent.

Comment: It seems `bash` and `bash -s` are also equivalent to `bash -i`.